# Is their any way to Invoke a specific delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

Let's say I have a `Player` script attach to player and then an `Enemy` script which is attach to all enemies in the scene like 20 enemies. If player killed one enemy then I have to call the `EnemyDied`  Function. If I make a delegate `EnemyKillDelegate` which will invoke when player killed any enemy then it will call the registered function `EnemyDied`, but in this case `EnemyDied` of every enemy will call which is definitely not what I want. Is there a way to specifically call the `EnemyDied` function of the enemy script which is died. I know I can `GetComponent` of Enemy which is died then call the function but *is there any different way to do this?*

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This Scrip is attach to only Player
    public static event Action EnemyKillDelegate;

    void EnemyDied()
    {
        EnemyKillDelegate?.Invoke();
    }
}

 
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This Scrip is attach to every enemy in the scene
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Player.EnemyKillDelegate += EnemyDied;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Player.EnemyKillDelegate -= EnemyDied;
    }

    void EnemyDied()
    {
        Debug.Log("I am Dead");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to see what you already tried to do. This site is for programming help, **not to provide code according to a set of task requirements**. Please retake the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and visit the [How to Ask pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think you took the wrong approach, the `Player` should kill the `Enemy`, but the `Enemy` should not ask the `Player` it has been killed

Comment: @Hervé I didn't completely get your point and also struggling with how to approach this problem, Kindly can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

What is a suitable approach instead, is to use a different delegate. No, it will not call the method of each `Enemy` game object, only of the one that subscribed to the delegate.

```
// in Player.cs
public delegate string EnemyKillDelegate(Player p);
public EnemyKillDelegate OnEnemyKilled;

// in Enemy.cs
string EnemyDied(Player p)
{
    Debug.Log("Player " + p.gameObject.name + " killed enemy " + gameOBject.name);
    return gameObject.name;
}
```

Then you can get the name of the killed enemy as follows:

```
string killedEnemy = EnemyKillDelegate?.Invoke(this);
```

Here `enemyName` can be null (given you continuously call `Player.EnemyDied()`). Also, you can omit the argument of the delegate (`Player p`), if there will be only one player.